# bad substitution when running ${} in centos terminal

Tags: linux, bash

i am writing below command in centos terminal

`RC=${docker wait dat_abcdetl_1`}

however getting the error:

```
-bash: ${docker wait  dat_abcdetl_1}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Why did you write it? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is probably :

```
RC=$(docker wait dat_abcdetl_1)
```

The `$(...)` construct is used for [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), whereas `${...}` is for [parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Answer (score 4):

`${...}` is a construct used for [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> When braces are used, the matching ending brace is the first ‘}’ not escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an embedded arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter expansion.

Judging from your example what you really want is [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command itself.

This would be written as:

```
RC=$(docker wait  dat_abcdetl_1)
```